# Disable 'open this page in [Application]' prompt (iOS)

Tags: security, ios, customization, bookmarks

I currently have an application called `App Icon`, which allows me to theme my iOS device without being jailbroken, by having web bookmarks on my homepage that open the other application that I want.

The problem is I have a theme for the Spotify application (or any for this matter), now when I open that shortcut, I always get a prompt asking me if I want to open that URL in Spotify.

As you can see, that is a bit of a problem since I want it to open the application without me pressing 'ok' every time. Is there a way I could disable this prompt (preferably for the specific home screen bookmark) or not?

If it helps, I am running the latest version of iOS 9.